# Composing Option<Enum> with closures that pattern-match arguments

Tags: enums, rust, pattern-matching, monads, combinators

I have an enum with two different possible "types" and a function that may return any of them, wrapped in an `Option`:

```
enum Possibilities {
    First(i32),
    Second(String),
}
use Possibilities::*;

fn some_poss() -> Option<Possibilities> {
    Some(Second(String::from("hi")))
}
```

I want to apply an operation to the result of `some_poss`, but this operation only makes sense for one of the possibilities of the enum, otherwise it should return `None`. For example:

```
let a: Option<i32> = some_poss().and_then(|poss| if let First(x) = poss {
    Some(x * 2)
} else {
    None
});
```

How can I concisely combine this operation? Would it be possible to write this in a way similar to the following?

```
// Compile error: pattern `Second(_)` not covered
let b: Option<i32> = some_poss().map(|First(x)| x * 2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to handle this specific case would be to create a method on the `enum` specifically for retrieving the one variant. Somewhat like [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok).

```
enum Possibilities {
    First(i32),
    Second(String),
}
use Possibilities::*;

impl Possibilities {
    fn first(self) -> Option<i32> {
        match self {
            Possibilities::First(x) => Some(x),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

This would allow you to implement your function like:

```
some_fun().and_then(|p| p.first()).map(|x| x * 2)
// or, if you prefer this style:
some_fun().and_then(Possibilities::first).map(|x| x * 2);
```

This makes it explicit what each step is doing - `some_poss` gets an `Option<Possiblities>`, then `first()` gets an `Option<i32>` from that `Possibilities`, and then `and_then` collapses `Option<Option<i32>>` into `Option<i32>`.

Comment: The problem I originally posted was a little too simple, I am actually using the`serde_json` library, and doing this would be somewhat cumbersome. However, turns out they implement this already! https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/enum.Value.html . So to any readers, know that you can look for this pattern in libraries.

Comment: This is an established pattern, so the example code should follow the established naming convention. Since this takes ownership, it should be `into_first`. There can be related functions for references (`as_first`) and mutable references (`as_first_mut`).

Comment: @Shepmaster definitely - sounds like a good idea. I was thinking `into` really makes sense when some internal thing is being transformed, String -> Vec, but I can see it making sense for this kind of unwrapping too.